# $scope.$on not firing on a modal angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to transfer model from one controller to another controller. 
    In my application i have a common controller where in i have wrote broadcast method.

Code flow goes as follows:

**SharedController:**

```
updateForEdit: function(data) {
         $rootScope.$broadcast('updateForEdit', data);
}
```

**1st controller:**

```
 SharedService.updateForEdit($scope.items);
```

After this line control is going to broadcast so works fine till here

**2nd controller:**

```
 $scope.$on('updateForEdit', function (testdata) {
            $scope.test=testdata;
        });
```

even after this line of code `$scope.test` doesn't have any value.

Please let me know how to get `model` which is sent in 1st controller.?

Answer (score 2):

At least part of the problem is that the data should come in as the second argument:

```
$scope.$on('updateForEdit', function (event, testdata) {
    $scope.test=testdata;
});
```

Comment: Added. Still $scope.test has no data

Comment: since 1st parameter is event.. does it wait for any event to fire?

Comment: You are firing the event when you do `$rootScope.$broadcast('updateForEdit', data)`, so it should work now. Can you verify that you are actually passing the correct data to `SharedService.updateForEdit`?

Comment: yes it is whole model from 1st controller. do i have to call any thing in 2nd one to enter on $on?

Comment: Something else may be wrong. Please post more code.